# form submit in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to create xml **after** form save/submit data,but it comes **before**

```
 <form action='/download' method='post'>

 <input type='submit' value='update' id='update'/>

 </form>
```

Now here is my jquery

```
 $('#update').live("click", function() {
alert('called');
   $.post( 'myxml.php', {username:$('#username').val() },
     function( data ) {
     alert(data);
     }); 
});
```

Comment: I need a way to do create xml in parallel with form submit...i want to do both

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with your current HTML code. Once the form submits, the page will be redirected, effectively killing all other running javascript.

However, there are ways to submit a form via jQuery without refreshing the page. I suggest you  follow [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) tutorial.

Or do this:

```
 $('#update').on("click", function() {
alert('called');
   $.post( 'myxml.php', {username:$('#username').val() },
     function( data ) {
     alert(data);
     $('form[action="/download"]').submit()
     }); 
     return false; //prevent bubble
});
```

Comment: I need a way to do create xml in parallel with form submit...i want to do both

Comment: as i have <input type='submit' so your code do exactly what my code...do need to submit..

Comment: @user2244804: No, it doesn't. It stops the event from bubbling out, _preventing_ the submit. Then, it waits for the response from the server and _then_ submits. Remove that line and and it will never submit.

Comment: `live` was deprecated in around 1.5 and removed in 1.9. You shouldn't use it (even if OP does)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see what the asker is trying to do nor what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JanDvorak: The asker is trying to wedge an extra POST request before he submits the form. Which means that he needs to pause or stop/resume the form submission. I'll remove the `live()`, I just copy pasted that bit of code from his question